# jQuery Mobile navigaton

Tags: jquery, mobile, navigation, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to create a mobile version of my views using jQuery Mobile, but it doesn't work like expected.

I have two pages - a.html has one jQuery Mobile page (`div` with `data-role="page"`) and a link to b.html which has several jQuery Mobile pages.  Now if I load a.html in my browser I can go to b.html and display the main "page", but any links inside b.html referring to other "page" divs inside b.html will fail (this are the hash links with `href` like `#otherpage`).  If I go straight to b.html all links work perfectly.

Is it possible to serve several "page" divs in b.html without breaking the navigation controls?

I'm using latest jQuery Mobile 1.0 alpha 4.1.

UPDATE

Framework I'm using is Ruby on Rails.

Part of my mobile layout:

```
<div data-role="page">
  <div data-role="content">
    <%= yield %>
  </div>
</div>
<%= yield :pages %>
```

Page a.html - that is an index action of a Rails scaffold:

```
<ul data-role="listview">
  <% @tv_series.each do |tv_series| %>
    <li><%= link_to tv_series.title, tv_series %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Page b.html - this are show actions of the same Rails scaffold:

```
<ul data-role="listview">
  <% @seasons.each do |season| %>
    <li>
      <!-- this are the links that work only if base page was b.html -->
      <a href="#season<%= season.id %>">Season <%= season.number %></a>
    </li>

    <%= render :partial => 'seasons/season.html.erb',
      :locals => { :season => season } %>

  <% end %>
</ul>
```

The season partial generates a new page div:

```
<% content_for :pages do %>
  <div data-role="page" id="season<%= season.id %>">
    <div data-role="content">
      whatever
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Now the error I get: if I go to scaffold index (`/tv_series`) and select one item, I go to show page with URL `/tv_series#/tv_series/:id` - the links I get on this page look like `/tv_series/tv_series/:id#season134` which is obviously wrong, jQuery Mobile tries an AJAX request and fails with page not found.  If I go to `/tv_series/:id` manually all the links look fine (`/tv_series/:id#season134`).

Comment: Since jQuery mobile builds its own giant dom made up of individual 'pages' as you navigate through your site, I wouldn't be surprised if it freaked out when you tried to access your own 'page' divs.  I have no information to back that up with, hence the comment. Have you tried turning your page divs into individual pages yet?  That shouldn't be hard to test with, and is basically the same result at the end of the day, anyway.

Comment: code would help, what does the debugger say? any errors?

Comment: revdrjrr - separate page for every div would require creating a lot of new controller actions and routes and I wanted to keep those the same as in the desktop version. Phill Pafford - it gets confused and produces some strange paths, will update the question with some code and results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I've found my answer in jQuery Mobile 1.0 alpha 4.1 documentation:

It's important to note if you are linking from a mobile page that was loaded via Ajax to a page that contains multiple internal pages, you need to add a rel="external" or data-ajax="false" to the link. This tells the framework to do a full page reload to clear out the Ajax hash in the URL. This is critical because Ajax pages use the hash (#) to track the Ajax history, while multiple internal pages use the hash to indicate internal pages so there will be conflicts in the hash between these two modes.

So with current navigation system it's just not possible.